# How to achieve increment in SELECT

Tags: sql-server

I need to show a column with existing table records or rows, That column value need to be in a format as below

```
PC/01-10-2019/0000-000001
```

Where as PC is a static text,  01-10-2019 is the date value we receive as a input parameter for the procedure and 0000-000001 need to be auto generated increment value.

Example :

```
    PC/01-10-2019/0000-000001
    PC/01-10-2019/0000-000002
    PC/01-10-2019/0000-000003
    PC/01-10-2019/0000-000004
```

How to achieve this in SQL Server?

Comment: A computed field with a sequence.

Comment: Is the auto generated value already in the table? If not, then there is actually no data from any table in this result., unless you wish to show additional columns. If you wish to generate to auto increment value on the fly, look into `ROW_NUMBER()` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15. Then you just need to do some data conversion and concatenation

Comment: It would be a good idea to add some background on this because it seems like an XY problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH N1 AS (SELECT N = NULL UNION ALL SELECT N = NULL), -- 2
     N2 AS (SELECT N = NULL FROM N1 CROSS JOIN N1 AS N), -- 4
     N3 AS (SELECT N = NULL FROM N2 CROSS JOIN N2 AS N), -- 16
     N4 AS (SELECT N = NULL FROM N3 CROSS JOIN N3 AS N), -- 256
     N5 AS (SELECT N = NULL FROM N4 CROSS JOIN N4 AS N), -- 65536
     Numbers AS (SELECT Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM N5)
SELECT 'PC/01-10-2019/0000-' + FORMAT(number, 'd:000000', 'en-US')
FROM Numbers
```